# Angularjs routing manual refresh

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angularjs-routing

I have an SPA anularjs app with a few pages.

Router Provider is configured as follows:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

var path = 'web/partials/views/';
$routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: path + 'home.html',
            //controller: 'mainController'
        })
        .when('/benefits', {
            templateUrl: path + 'benefits.html',
            //controller: 'aboutController'
        })
        .when('/gallery', {
            templateUrl: path + 'gallery.html',
            //controller: 'contactController'
        })
        .when('/quote', {
            templateUrl: path + 'quote.html',
            //controller: 'contactController'
        });
```

This works - think nav links on index.html work and the address bar gets the correct url (myapp.com/benefits, myapp.com/quote, etc.)

What doesn't work is going directly to myapp.com/quote or myapp.com/benefits or other pages. I get "resource does't exists" - which makes sense - resource really doesn't exist.

My question is what is the appropriate way to handle this i AngularJS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are error handlers (like $routeChangeError) which you could utilize to redirect to a default page, check this out:

[angular route service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example)